# notifyDataSetChanged() with PagerAdapter in Android

Tags: android

I put the view pager in list view as row and want to update content of view pager when I scroll the list view . I have tried with  =

```
 @Override
        public int getCount() {

            // return PAGE_NUM;
            Log.e("intCount8888: "," = " +intCount );
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return intCount;

        }
```

and I have calling the notifyDataSetChange on list Adapter also in getView()

```
  @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        Holder holder = null;
        if (row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.txt_Descid = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textDescid);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_Desc);
            holder.txtInitialLetter = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_InitialLetter);
            holder.txtRemark = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textRemark);

            holder.imgBtn_Rework = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButtonRework);
            holder.imgBtn_FollowUp = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButtonFoloowUp);
            holder.imgBtn_RateEquipMent = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButtonRateEquipment);
            holder.imgBtn_Camera = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButtonCamera);
            holder.imgBtn_Audio = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButtonAudio);
            holder.imgBtn_FollowInspector = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgButtonFollowInspector);

            holder.viewPager = (ViewPager) row.findViewById(R.id.Image_ViewPagers);

            holder.viewPager.setPageMargin(-50);
            holder.viewPager.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
            holder.viewPager.setFadingEdgeLength(20);
            holder.viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
            holder.viewPager.setPadding(-5, 0, 0, 0);
            MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getContext());

            holder.viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            holder.viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //holder.viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();


            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
        }

        All_Post all_Post = data.get(position);


        holder.txt_Descid.setText(Integer.toString(all_Post.getID()));
        String strTextDescId = holder.txt_Descid.getText().toString().trim();
        Log.e("strTextDescId ", " = " + strTextDescId);
        getActivityId(strTextDescId);
        getActivityObjectId_Count();

        holder.txtTitle.setText(all_Post.getName());
        String strTxtTitle = holder.txtTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        Log.e("strTxtTitle ", " = " + strTxtTitle);


        holder.txtInitialLetter.setText(all_Post.getInitName());
        holder.txtRemark.setText(all_Post.getStrDesc());

        holder.imgBtn_Rework.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("Button click ", "event is fire");

            }
        });
```

But getting error

```
08-07 05:56:27.806    4475-4475/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at java.lang.IntegralToString.convertInt(IntegralToString.java:209)
            at java.lang.IntegralToString.appendInt(IntegralToString.java:173)
            at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:139)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page$MyPagerAdapter.getCount(AllPosts_Page.java:553)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:882)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2905)
            at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
            at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page$MyPagerAdapter.getCount(AllPosts_Page.java:554)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:882)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2905)
            at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
            at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page$MyPagerAdapter.getCount(AllPosts_Page.java:554)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:882)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2905)
            at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
            at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page$MyPagerAdapter.getCount(AllPosts_Page.java:554)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:882)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2905)
            at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
            at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page$MyPagerAdapter.getCount(AllPosts_Page.java:554)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:882)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2905)
            at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
            at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page$MyPagerAdapter.getCount(AllPosts_Page.java:554)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:882)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2905)
            at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
            at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page$MyPagerAdapter.getCount(AllPosts_Page.java:554)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:882)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2905)
            at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
            at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page$MyPagerAdapter.getCount(AllPosts_Page.java:554)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:882)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2905)
            at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
            at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page$MyPagerAdapter.getCount(AllPosts_Page.java:554)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:882)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2905)
            at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
            at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
            at com.example.tazeen.classnkk.AllPosts_Page$MyPagerAdapter.getCount(AllPost
```

Answer (score 3):

Notifydatasetchange() is used to tell adapter to update its list, when the data has changed. You do not call it in getView() or in getCount(). You have to call notifyDataSetChanged(), if you have added or removed any list item from the list View.

getView() method will inflate the view when you scroll the lisview. And getCount() method just returns the number of list items that ListView contains.

Comment: Thanks to reply , can you please explain me or suggest me how to do .  .

Comment: On phone so its hard to, but i can try. Whatever your using for data in adapter it must be a List of something, list of strings for instance. GetCount just needs to return the list.size() or the array.length. getView inflated that particular element in the list. So you grab it like theList.get(position). So if its like a string it be simple, if its a list of containers with bunch of data than peal out each piece and attach it in the getView(). But no need for notifydatasetchange unless you removed an item or added an item to the list of items.

Comment: Comment back if you dont get it. When i get to a pc ill throw down some code. Good luck